# Will i be able to see the SpaceX tonight launch from Ocala, Fl?

Tags: spacex, rockets, launch

Im currently in Ocala, FL and SpaceX launches a rocket tonight (March 9th) from Cape Canaveral. Will I be able to see it given the proper conditions?

Comment: You are north and west. The launch is to the east, and I THINK a bit to the north.  Get as high as possible in a building with a window facing East and a bit south.